# multiple expectations/assertions to verify test result

Tags: c#, tdd, bdd

I have read in several book and articles about TDD and BDD that one should avoid multiple assertions or expectations in a single unit test or specification. And I can understand the reasons for doing so. Still I am not sure what would be a good way to verify a complex result.

Assuming a method under test returns a complex object as a result (e.g. deserialization or database read) how do I verify the result correctly?

1.Asserting on each property:

```
  Assert.AreEqual(result.Property1, 1);
  Assert.AreEqual(result.Property2, "2");
  Assert.AreEqual(result.Property3, null);
  Assert.AreEqual(result.Property4, 4.0);
```

2.Relying on a correctly implemented .Equals():

```
Assert.AreEqual(result, expectedResult);
```

The disadvantage  of 1. is that if the first assert fails all the following asserts are not run, which might have contained valuable information to find the problem. Maintainability might also be a problem as Properties come and go.

The disatvantage of 2. is that I seem to be testing more than one thing with this test. I might get false positives or negatives if .Equals() is not implemented correctly. Also with 2. I do not see, what properties are actually different if the test fails but I assume that can often be addressed with a decent .ToString() override. In any case I think I should avoid to be forced to throw the debugger at the failing tests to see the difference. I should see it right away.

The next problem with 2. is that it compares the **whole** object even though for some tests only **some** properties might be significant.

What would be a decent way or best practise for this in TDD and BDD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the context present in the question I'd go for option 1.

It likely depends on context. If I'm using some sort of built in object serialization within the .NET framework, I can be reasonably assured that if no errors were encountered then the entire object was appropriately marshaled. In that case, asserting a single field in the object is probably fine. I trust MS libraries to do the right thing.

If you are using SQL and manually mapping results to domain objects I feel that option 1 makes it quicker to diagnose when something breaks than option 2. Option 2 likely relies on `toString` methods in order to render the assertion failure:

```
Expected <1 2 null 4.0> but was <1 2 null null>
```

Now I am stuck trying to figure out what field 4.0/null was. Of course I could put the field name into the method:

```
Expected <Property1: 1, Property2: 2, Property3: null, Property4: 4.0>
 but was <Property1: 1, Property2: 2, Property3: null, Property4: null>
```

This is fine for small numbers of properties, but begins to break down larger numbers of properties due to wrapping, etc. Also, the `toString` maintenance could become an issue as it needs to change at the same rate as the `equals` method.

Of course there is no correct answer, at the end of the day, it really boils down to your team's (or your own) personal preference.

Hope that helps!

Brandon

Answer (score 2):

Don't take TDD advice literally. What the "good guys" mean is that you should test one thing per test (to avoid a test failing for multiple reasons and subsequently having to debug the test to find the cause).
Now test "one thing" means "one behavior" ; NOT one assert per test IMHO.

It's a guideline not a rule.

So options:
For comparing whole data value objects

- If the object already exposes a usable production Equals, use it.
- Else do not add a Equals just for testing ([See also Equality Pollution](http://xunitpatterns.com/Test%20Logic%20in%20Production.html)). Use a helper/extension method (or you could find one in an assertion library) obj1.HasSamePropertiesAs(obj2)

For comparing unstructured parts of objects (set of arbitrary properties - which should be rare),

- create a well named private method AssertCustomerDetailsInOrderEquals(params) so that the test is clear in what part you're actually testing. Move the set of assertions into the private method.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the second approach by default. You're right, this fails if `Equals()` is not implemented correctly, but if you've implemented a custom `Equals()`, you should have unit-tested it too.

The second approach is in fact more abstract and consise and allows you to modify the code easier later, allowing in the same way to reduce code duplication. Let's say you choose the first approach:

- You'll have to compare all properties in several places,
- If you add a new property to a class, you'll have to add a new assertion in unit tests; modifying your `Equals()` would be much easier. Of course you have still to add a value of the property in expected result (if it's not the default value), but it would be shorter to do than adding a new assertion.

Also, it **is** much easier to see what properties are actually different with the second approach. You just run your tests in debug mode, and compare the properties on break.

By the way, you should never use `ToString()` for this. I suppose you wanted to say `[DebuggerDisplay]` attribute?

> The next problem with 2. is that it compares the whole object even though for some tests only some properties might be significant.

If you have to compare only some properties, than:

- ether you **refactor your code by implementing a base class which contains only those properties**. Example: if you want to compare a `Cat` to another `Cat` but only considering the properties common to `Dog` and other animals, implement `Cat : Animal` and compare the base class.
- or you do what you've done in your first approach. Example: if you do care only about the quantity of milk the expected and the actual cats have drunk and their respective names, you'll have two assertions in your unit test.

Comment: I tend to disagree on having to throw the debugger at the failing test to see the differences. Also DebuggerDisplay doesn't show up in the test report, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Try "one aspect of behavior per test" rather than "one assertion per test". If you need more than one assertion to illustrate the behavior you're interested in, do that.

For instance, your example might be `ShouldHaveSensibleDefaults`. Splitting that up into `ShouldHaveADefaultNameAsEmptyString`, `ShouldHaveNullAddress`, `ShouldHaveAQuantityOfZero` etc. won't read as clearly. Nor will it help to hide the sensible defaults in another object then do a comparison.

However, I *would* separate examples where the values had defaults with any properties derived from some logic somewhere, for instance, `ShouldCalculateTheTotalQuantity`. Moving small examples like this into their own method makes it more readable.

You might also find that different properties on your object are changed by different contexts. Calling out each of these contexts and looking at those properties separately helps me to see how the context relates to the outcome.

Dave Astels, who came up with the "one assertion per test", now uses the phrase ["one aspect of behavior"](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/behaviour-driven-development.html) too, though he still finds it useful to [separate that behavior](http://techblog.daveastels.com/2006/08/27/one-expectation-per-example-a-remake-of-one-assertion-per-test/). I tend to err on the side of readability and maintainability, so if it makes pragmatic sense to have more than one assertion, I'll do that.